# What to place beneath the vegetables before placing them on the baking tray?

Tags: baking, oven

In order to prevent their surface from burning, what can be placed beneath vegetables to be roasted before placing them on the baking tray?

I am thinking of applying oil to the tray, but I'm not sure if that's enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually put tinfoil down and then lightly oil it. If done carefully, the tray stays clean and doesn't need to be washed and the foil can be thrown out (or used for a second batch of veggies if you have one).

Comment: by tinfoil you mean aluminium foil used for wrapping breads?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Yes, I meant aluminum foil, but I still hear it often called "tinfoil". ...I guess from when it was made of tin?

Comment: does the vegetable burn if tinfoil isn't used?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: No, you can oil the baking tray and put the vegetables directly on that. But then you will have to clean the baking tray after. I like to use foil on the tray because I've gotten good enough that the tray stays completely clean and doesn't need to be washed after I'm done with it.

Comment: cleaning the tray is not a problem for me, I am just worried about the burning food. Is there something called baking sheet too?

Comment: @AnishaKaul: To me, a "baking sheet" and "baking tray" are probably the same thing. Oiling the surface that the vegetables go on will prevent them from sticking to the surface and burning, but if it's too hot, they will probably burn no matter what.

Comment: " To me, a "baking sheet" and "baking tray" are probably the same thing." Oh, I read that term on this website, thought that's something different. :doh: Thanks.

Comment: @AnishaKaul: I think "baking tray" is British English.

Comment: @Jefromi They should fix a particular English standard for this site ;) to avoid confusions. :D

Comment: A tray suggests a highish lip around the outside, a sheet suggests little or no lip.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Does lip or no lip make a difference in cooking? Lip may work as a handle for sure.

Comment: A lip is better for roasting (which is why roasting tins have big ones) because they prevent the food from burning quickly. A lipless sheet is used mainly in baking.

Comment: This answer, and some of the comments concern me (Someone who tries to be environmentally conscious). Save the environmental damage that production, transport, and post-use "storage" of the tinfoil produces, in lieu of a spray of oil and a couple of minutes of cleaning something that has a far longer life. Also, not to be taken literally - What is the point in using a tray, when your food is actually sitting on another surface?

Comment: @user66001: I have a small kitchen with a small sink. The baking trays do not really fit in the sink so cleaning them is awkward and difficult when the baked item burns and sticks to it (oil helps, but then there's a sticky and oily mess to clean, instead of a burnt one). The last place I lived had a large dishwasher which could easily hold trays, so in that case, I wouldn't bother with using foil since clean-up was much easier.

Comment: @user66001: *" What is the point in using a tray, when your food is actually sitting on another surface?"* Do you mean the foil as "another surface"? The foil is very thin. If you try to lift a piece of foil covered in vegetables, the foil will flex and bend, and the vegetables may fall off.

Comment: FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - It is a pity that some places have sinks which are ill equiped to deal with cleanup of their "owners" projects :) As for the two surfaces, was more speaking to idea of the tray being designed to function for the intended purpose, and (assuming ways of cleaning it) the unnessary need for the tinfoil. I am just one of those that wonder what Earth will look like in years to come, given the current rate of use of it's resources, which drives me to try to reduce my impact as much as I can (Blood, sweat and tears, for the most part, be damned) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid oil altogether if you cover your baking trays in [parchment paper](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-parchment-paper.htm). Just make sure that you fit the paper to the shape of the tray and don't be surprised if the edges turn brown/black at higher (400 degrees and up) temperatures.

If you need help locating parchment paper, I would suggest visiting nearby restaurant supply stores, checking out your local supermarket (Reynolds has a brand of parchment paper available), or utilizing an online store such as [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&rh=i%3aaps,k%3aparchment%20paper&page=1#/ref=sr_kk_1?rh=i%3aaps,k%3aparchment%20paper%20for%20baking&keywords=parchment%20paper%20for%20baking&ie=UTF8&qid=1333037594) or [King Arthur Flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/shop/items/parchment-paper-half-sheet).

Oh, and one last thing: I recommend parchment paper because I used to volunteer as a prep cook and we would constantly use it to bake things like fish sticks, pizza pockets, and vegetables. Why? Because nothing got stuck on the pans, nothing got burnt, and clean up involved stripping off the paper, wading it up, and throwing it in the garbage. Now if that's not easy, I don't know what is.

Answer (score 2):

I love using foil, but only for certain things.  And now that I paid $9 for a large roll, I won’t use it as much anymore. It also tends to turn potatoes a bit grey and I can taste the foil.

The Irish girl that I am, I love using enamel roasting pans.  Here is the trick, put the pan in the oven first to pre-heat. Then in a bowl add your potatoes (well rinsed), carrots (cut smaller) or mix in some sweet potatoes.  Add your spices then oil and toss.  In 10 mins when the pan is hot, pull out the rack with the pan, then throw in the mix. A lot of sizzling goes on.  Halfway through the cooking process, toss the mix and cook some more, I always use loud timers.  The potatoes don't stick or burn, unless your oven is too high or you leave them in too long.  If they do stick towards the end, just pull it out and let the pan cool.  The potatoes will then release on their own.

The great thing about enamel pans, they darken your potatoes and carrots to such a sweet flavor.  Also, when they start to get a buildup you can throw them in your self-cleaning oven.  Just lean it up on one side.  Remember, your self-cleaning oven sides are enamel.

Comment: +1 ... and save all that disposable tinfoil/parchment paper! :)